# Force close doesn't exit android application, instead opens a previous activity in very buggy state

Tags: android

The problem that I'm having is when running my android app, if I run into a force close error or pause the application with a breakpoint in debug mode and then press 'stop', the app doesn't quit, instead the first activity on my activity stack is opened but it is in a very buggy state. The activity is a library of books and when it is opened after the force close or by stopping, all of the users books are gone, the labels on the options menu are gone (although the icons are still there) and almost any action results in a force close.

So basically I'm wondering why stopping the application in debug mode, or running into a force close doesn't shut down the whole application and instead opens the first activity in a very buggy state.

I can't give specific code because the force close only happened once and I didn't get the stack trace. I realize this is a very generic question and I understand if it's too little information to go off of I just wanted to see if anyone else had run into something similar.

Edit: It seems as though force close just closes the current activity and tries to open the previous activity on the stack. However somehow my application context is getting destroyed so when the previous activity opens and looks for information in the application context, such as books in the user's library, there is nothing there.

Comment: Has your problem been resolved?  There appear to be some acceptable answers provided.  The Android tag is bursting with unanswered questions and we are trying to close as many as possible.  Your assistance in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: yes it has, sorry forgot about this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run into a force-close, your app's process is killed. If your activity stack had an activity behind the one that crashed, it is restarted in a new process. When the process dies, so does the application context. The new process creates a new application context, which is why you're not seeing your data in there.

See http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/b274cfa64b17f535?pli=1 for a discussion on this.

One way to address your specific problem is to add a flag in your Application object, that you explicitly set to true after your shared data is loaded. You can then check for this flag in your Activity's onCreate() to confirm that the data is available. If the flag is false, you can call finish()

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me a few times. I've noticed that when I have a stack of activities and I start the second without closing the first, then a "force close" on the second only stops the second activity. Since the first activity is still running, it comes to the forefront.

Example. Activity A is running. Clicking on a button opens activity B. (I didn't finish() activity A) Activity B for some reason 'force closes'. Activity A comes into view since its still running.

Comment: You're right it does seem to just force close the opened activity and resume the previous one. Do you know if there's any way to check in the onResume method if a force close has occurred, and if so to finish() the activity?

Comment: You might want to avoid those weird call backs. I'd suggest just finishing the activity before starting the next one. Ideally you want to make sure that force closes don't occur. To prevent force closes you could set up a global exception handler. This might help http://www.nomachetejuggling.com/2006/06/13/java-5-global-exception-handling/

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, however they're not really what I'm looking for. It's not always possible or desirable to finish the activity before starting the next one. That's the whole point of having the activity stack, so that the user can navigate backwards through their previously opened activities. Of course ideally having no force closes is optimal, but sometimes they can get through unnoticed and I'd like to be able to deal with it properly when it happens. Finally, I'd like to deal with the exception as close to the occurrence as possible, and avoid the global exception handler.

Comment: I'm going to keep looking for a way to determine if the previous activity force closed in the onResume() method of the current activity, or something similar to this. Thanks for your thoughts though.