# App partially closing

Tags: android, android-service

I'm building an application using a service and the fragment compatibility pack and am running into some weird behavior. I have a FragmentActivity and a ListFragment which implements LoaderCallbacks, and when the FragmentActivity starts it kicks off a service to download data and fill in a database.

Suppose I'm on that screen, and I navigate past it by clicking on one of the rows of the ListFragment. If I then hit a nullpointer, or any other exception that causes the regular force close dialog to pop up, I hit the force close button on the dialog and the activity I'm on does indeed get shut down, but I end up back on the FragmentActivity screen, rather than say my Android/launcher home screen.

To me this says that the app is crashing but somehow the fragment activity is getting restarted. The behavior occurs if I hit the red stop button in the debug view in eclipse - the current activity gets killed but that damn fragment activity is still there.

Obviously I don't want my app to ever get a force close dialog, but really what I'm trying to figure out is if this is a symptom of me not coding something correctly. Currently I never stop the service, mostly because it gets reused over and over again throughout the app and I haven't gotten around to coding up a way to close the service safely without prematurely ending a new request to it.

Is the service keeping a reference to the Activity via the ListFragment and LoaderCallback or something? Why is this FragmentActivity seemingly invincible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because your process is killed, but there are other activities on the activity stack. This is the expected behavior, as the system attempts to start a new process on the next activity on the stack once your offending activity was removed. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067994/force-close-doesnt-exit-android-application-instead-opens-a-previous-activity) and [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/b274cfa64b17f535?pli=1).

If you want to remove all of your activities off the stack after a force close, one thing you can do is hit the back button until you are taken to the home screen. Unless you override the behavior of the back button in your app, it destroys your current activity and takes you to the previous activity. Once there are no more activities left, you will be taken to the home screen and can start your app again from eclipse, and it will start you off at your main activity.

Answer (score 0):

i had run into similar problems, with Databse loading and Nullpointer Exceptions. I don't know your special case but it might help to separate the Databse out into a Content Provider if you aren't already doing that, that way you are decoupling the Fragments form the Database more, it might help with the errors.

Comment: thanks for the response, but i think you misunderstood my question. I'm not having problems with nullpointers or other exceptions. I'm just wonder why it is that when i do screw up and make one, why is my app not fulling closing. I'm worried that my service is automatically restarting my activities or something like that.